# Plone and nginx configuration does not return any apparent results

Tags: plone

I'm trying to configure nginx to run with plone, but I'm not having success.I don't get any errors when testing nginx with "/etc/init.d/nginx configtest" after creating my mysite.conf file, I restart nginx so that it can pick up the changes and I also don't get any errors,but the moment I type the URL configured in the browser, no content or message is displayed. Does anyone know what may be happening?

My configuration file is below:

```
upstream plone {
    #define grupo de servidores que podem ser acessados
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server ---.--.--.--:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.error.log;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /VirtualHostBase/http/www.mysite.com:80/teste/VirtualHostRoot/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        #proxy_pass http://plone/VirtualHostBase/http/localhost:8080/teste/VirtualHostRoot/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http:/mysite.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: You should ask this in our forum, https://community.plone.org. Please see https://plone.org/support on how to best get help with Plone